# How to use map that has more than one output?

Tags: rust

So far I use the `map` function as a 1-1 relationship, such as the following example:

```
let vector = [1, 2, 3];
let result: Vec<_> = vector.iter().map(|x| x * 2).map(|x| x + 1).collect();
println!("After mapping: {:?}", result);
// After mapping: [3, 5, 7]
```

In this example there are 2 `map` function and both function are having a 1-1 relationship. I would like to know how could I change the code such that the first map function could provide output multiple (e.g. 2) output to the second map function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a 1-to-many relationship in the context of your example, you can use the `flat_map` function. Here's how you can modify your code:

```rust
let vector = [1, 2, 3];
let result: Vec<_> = vector
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|x| vec![x * 2, x * 3]) // Modify this line to produce multiple outputs
    .map(|x| x + 1)
    .collect();
println!("After mapping: {:?}", result);
```

In this example, `flat_map` takes a closure that produces an iterator, and the results are flattened into a single iterator. Here, I used `vec![x * 2, x * 3]` to produce two outputs for each element in the original vector. The subsequent `map` then operates on each of these values, resulting in the final mapped vector `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]`.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using a `Vec` here rather than just an array? I'll admit to having some bad habits in Rust (comes of initially learning it for code golf), but I'm not seeing any advantage to making a `Vec` over an array when it will be implicitly iterated and discarded a moment later.

Comment: Using a `Vec` allows dynamic resizing, accommodating variable outputs. Arrays have a fixed size, suitable when the number of elements is known and constant.

Comment: If dynamic resizing isn't needed, using an array or iterator can be more memory-efficient than a Vec for temporary values.

Answer (score 3):

If the output from one `map` should become two values as arguments to the next `map`, the easiest way is to have the first `map` produce a `tuple`, and the second accept the `tuple` with destructuring.

For example:

```
let result: Vec<_> = vector.iter().map(|x|(x * x, x * 2)).map(|(square, double)| square > double).collect();
```

which computes the square and the doubling of input values in a `tuple`, then destructures them in the next `map`'s arguments.

Note the distinction between `|(square, double)|` (a closure taking a single argument known to be a two-`tuple` that can be destructured) and `|square, double|` (a closure taking two arguments). `map` only passes and receives single arguments, but thanks to destructuring, you can simulate passing an arbitrary number of arguments).

If the goal is to produce multiple values but still pass them individually as arguments to the next layer (e.g. 10 calls to the first `map` closure produce 20 calls to the next `map` closure), then `flat_map` is the way to go; just replace `map` with `flat_map`, and produce arrays of values instead of single values:

```
let result: Vec<_> = vector.iter().flat_map(|x|[x, -x]).map(|x| x + 1).collect();
```

which produces one more than the positive and negative value of each input.

Comment: Just to emphasize, note the extra parentheses in the second closure (`|(square, double)|` rather than `|square, double|`). That's not a two-argument function. That's a one-argument function that does some clever destructuring, which is why we're allowed to use `map` (which takes one-argument functions) at all here.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Just added a paragraph to emphasize that point. Definitely a good thing to include for people who are new to Rust.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am not sure but I tried your code in rust playground. It seems to me that it didn't give 2 output from the first map. Also the second example doesn't compile.

Comment: @Winston: The second example was because I brain-farted and forgot to actually use `flat_map` there (now fixed). The first one is answering a question that is similar to yours but applies in different scenarios (your question was phrased in a sufficiently ambiguous way that you could have meant either a `map` producing two things at a time which are two *inputs* at a time to the next `map`, or producing two things at a time which are passed to two discrete invocations of the next `map`).